# Populate external .html file with moustache?

Tags: javascript, hogan.js

Assume I have jQuery code that loads an external html file to the template.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  $('#content').load('file.html');
});
```

Now, I want to populate some fields in the `file.html` file. Is that possible?

Comment: Consider including the contents of `file.html` here (or at least a good representative example of what it might include).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an (untested) example of how you might do this.

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {

  // load text into a hidden div.
  $('#hiddenContent').load('file.html', function() {

    // grab template from hidden div
    var templateString = $('#hiddenContent').html();

    // compile the template string into a template object
    var compiledTemplate = hogan.compile(templateString);

    // apply some data to the template
    var parsedTemplate = compiledTemplate.render({...some data});

    // finally, show the parsed template
    $('#content').html(parsedTemplate);
  }
});
```

Edit: additional notes

Ideally, you wouldn't load `file.html` into a dom element because it doesn't need to be shown. Just load the text.

Also, compiling templates is computationally expensive. In a production environment, these templates should be pre-compiled. Hogan has a command-line util called Hulk that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('#content').load('file.html', function() {
    // do something to populate fields created by the loading of file.html
  }
});
```